# Ip6tables firewall make server unreachable on reboot

Tags: networking, firewall, ipv6

I am trying to set up a very basic firewall on my server with iptables and ip6tables.

My rules get loaded on restart with systemD. The OS is ArchLinux.

When I just setup iptables everything works. Also rebooting.

As soon as I activate my ip6table rules, enable them in systemD and reboot the server I loose all connections and have to reinstall.

Is there anything im missing for ipv6 that needs to be enabled on a server? I have read about changes reagarding ICMP.

Here are my rules for ipv4 and ipv6

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP



ip6tables -F
ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Comment: You're missing rules to allow important ICMP packets. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4890 (Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls)

Comment: I just added ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT . It still fails to connect. Am I missing sth else?

Comment: I think it should be `-p icmpv6`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work either. I posted in the forums of the provider for now. But thanks for the help and link to the RFC.

Comment: Do you lose your IPv4 access too? That should work separately. If it crashes IPv4, there must be something deeper wrong, other than your IPv6 filtering rules. Maybe a bad module pertaining to IPv6?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this @b-m-f? I think I've just encountered a similar issue.

Comment: nope sry. maybe its easiest to disable ipv6. Or try nftables with the inet filter. Way easier